# Whoy doesn't openssh-server work in ubuntu14.04

Tags: openssh

Here is all what I can show.

---

```
[skynet]~> apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up openssh-server (1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.3) ...
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match ssh Default-Stop values (none)
invoke-rc.d: initscript ssh, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


[skynet]~> uname -a
Linux skynet.tumo.lab 3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:42:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[skynet]~> ps aux | grep ssh
root       550  0.0  0.1  43128  1472 ?        Ss   Sep07   0:00 **/usr/share/centrifydc/sbin/sshd -D**
root      3472  0.0  0.2  42916  3052 pts/3    S+   14:31   0:00 ssh web15
root      4050  0.0  0.3  42916  3056 pts/2    S+   14:36   0:00 ssh web15
root      8173  0.0  0.4  97552  4164 ?        Ss   15:14   0:00 sshd: root@pts/5                     
root      8307  0.0  0.3  42916  3064 pts/5    S+   15:14   0:00 ssh gm-st02
root      8308  0.0  0.4  97552  4160 ?        Ss   15:14   0:00 sshd: root@pts/6                     
root      8370  0.0  0.3  42916  3064 pts/6    S+   15:14   0:00 ssh sk-st01
root     12427  0.0  0.4  97552  4160 ?        Ss   15:45   0:00 sshd: root@pts/7                     
root     12490  0.0  0.2  42916  3052 pts/7    S+   15:45   0:00 ssh sk-st02
root     14072  0.0  0.4  97552  4212 ?        Ss   11:43   0:00 sshd: root@pts/1                     
root     15545  0.0  0.0   8864   648 pts/4    S+   16:14   0:00 grep ssh
root     16775  0.0  0.5  99424  5968 ?        Ss   11:58   0:01 sshd: root@pts/0                     
root     18084  0.0  0.4  97552  4212 ?        Ss   12:06   0:00 sshd: root@pts/2                     
root     20720  0.0  0.4  97552  4204 ?        Ss   12:29   0:00 sshd: root@pts/3                     
root     21668  0.0  0.4  98112  4812 ?        Ss   12:33   0:00 sshd: root@pts/4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a apt-get purge openssh-server. Reboot and then try to reinstall. For the install do an update first then the install.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no use, the same thing, I guess the problem is this /usr/share/centrifydc/sbin/sshd package, how do you think?

Comment: from what i can see openssh was already installed. According to you ps another sshd client is installed. can you confirm that.

Comment: I do, do you think I should stop it before upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have installed centrifydc-openssh, stopping that service does not help, but when I remove it everything works fine.
I had no this problem before, this started recently, I do dist-upgrade regularly, probably this started on kernel version 3.13.039.
I have no thi problem on fresh installations with kernel 3.19.